# Using exceptions for control flow

Tags: java, exception, language-agnostic

I have read that using exceptions for control flow is not good, but how can I achieve the following easily without throwing exceptions? So if user enters username that is already in use, I want to show error message next to the input field. Here is code from my sign up page backing bean:

```
public String signUp() {
    User user = new User(username, password, email);

    try {
        if ( userService.save(user) != null ) {
            // ok
        }
        else {
            // not ok
        }
    }
    catch ( UsernameInUseException e ) {
        // notify user that username is already in use
    }
    catch ( EmailInUseException e ) {
        // notify user that email is already in use
    }
    catch ( DataAccessException e ) {
        // notify user about db error
    }

    return "index";
}
```

save method of my userService:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User save(User user) {
    if ( userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null ) {
        LOGGER.debug("Username '{}' is already in use", user.getUsername());
        throw new UsernameInUseException();
    }
    else if ( userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null ) {
        LOGGER.debug("Email '{}' is already in use", user.getEmail());
        throw new EmailInUseException();
    }

    user.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt()));
    user.setRegisteredOn(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC));

    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: Are you using any framework? or is it just plain Servlet-JSP based web-application?

Comment: I'm using JSF 2.2, Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using exceptions works like anything else you do. You can use it but don't overdo it.

In general you want to throw an exception when something happened that was not right, but your program can recover from, probably in another module. Exceptions help to put the program (more precisely the run-time stack) in a good state, so you can do something about the error.

Using return values is usually not a good idea and often seen as not-so-good design.

In your case the exception will most likely trigger a message to the user, which happens in the UI and should be apart from the signup logic itself, so using an exception seems appropriate.

Now for the part of overdoing it. You can easily do a single exception such as SignupException that encloses a reason why it went wrong. You probably don't want to end up with a system that has more exception classes than classes with productive code.